# Matching version number parts with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, version

I'm trying to match the parts of a version number (Major.Minor.Build.Revision) with C# regular expressions. However, I'm pretty new to writing Regex and even using Expresso is proving to be a little difficult. Right now, I have this:

```
(?<Major>\d*)\.(?<Minor>\d*)\.(?<Build>\d*)\.(?<Revision>\d*)
```

This works, but requires that every part of the version number exists. What I would like to do is also match versions like:

```
2.13
```

In this case, the Build and Revision groups need to return null values. Feel free to suggest a better method if I'm going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(?<Major>\d*)\.(?<Minor>\d*)(\.(?<Build>\d*)(\.(?<Revision>\d*))?)?
```

Makes the third and fourth parts optional.

Comment: Voted up because I was 3 seconds from clicking post with the same answer :)

Comment: Thank you! In past attempts, I was enclosing each group in its own Zero or More expression, rather than nesting them.

Comment: @sean.bright: thanks, and bad luck.  There is still a fastest-gun-in-the-west problem, of sorts. :D

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't a regex, but [System.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) does all the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Tested in VBScript, this pattern:

```
^(\d+)(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?$
```

Will validate all the following True:

- 23
- 23.1
- 23.1.1
- 23.1.1.1

And the following all False:

- 23.11.11.33.11
- 23.43 2.1
- 44.11.2 3
- 3q.4.2.1
- 3.4.
- 4.3.21a

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Regex you could try:

```
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fvi = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(<string filePath>);

int major = fvi.FileMajorPart;
int minor = fvi.FileMinorPart;
int build = fvi.FileBuildPart;
```

Comment: Is there no possibility to get Revison? `Ma.Mi.B.R`

Answer (score 0):

Above   answer not working properly

```
(?<Major>\d*)\.(?<Minor>\d*)(\.(?<Build>\d*)(\.(?<Revision>\d*))?)?
```

try this one,

```
  var regularExpression = @"^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$";
                var regex = Regex.IsMatch("1.0.0.0", regularExpression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
                Console.WriteLine(regex);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

`(?<Major>\d*)\.?(?<Minor>\d*)?\.?(?<Build>\d*)?\.?(?<Revision>\d*)?`

I simply added some "zero or one" quantifiers to the capture groups and also to the dots just in case they are not there.

Comment: That allows 2.13.. as a valid number; also 2.13..13.