# How to use Assembly Version as Package Version when generating NuGet package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, versioning

I auto-increment assembly/file version numbers using a T4 Text Template that generates an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file looking like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.525")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.525")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0.525")]
```

The project is set to generate a package on build. However, the created package file name always ends with `*.1.0.0.nupkg` because the `<Version>` element is missing in the `csproj`-file.

Is there a way to use the versions specified in `AssemblyInfo.cs` as the package version?

Comment: This is what helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28363076/303696

Answer (score 0):

This is due to some syntactical incompatibility between Visual Studio and NuGet.
To make this really work, you need to change AssemblyInformationalVersion to something more like `1.0.0-build.525` or for older NuGet `1.0.0-build00525`.