# msbuild task to read AssemblyFileVersion of dll

Tags: msbuild, versioning

I need to read `AssemblyFileVersion` of dll instead of just `Version`.  I tried:

```
<Target Name="RetrieveIdentities">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="some.dll">
        <Output
            TaskParameter="Assemblies"
            ItemName="MyAssemblyIdentities"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Message Text="%(MyAssemblyIdentities.FileVersion)" />
</Target>
```

The script runs but doesn't output anything.  If I change `FileVersion` to `Version` it correctly outputs the `AssemblyVersion`.  How do I get `AssemblyFileVersion` with my script?

Answer (score 5):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19673718/44853), I was able to create a custom MSBuild task:

```
<UsingTask
  TaskName="GetFileVersion"
  TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
  AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">

  <ParameterGroup>
    <AssemblyPath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    <Version ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Using Namespace="System.Diagnostics" />
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      <![CDATA[
      Log.LogMessage("Getting version details of assembly at: " + this.AssemblyPath, MessageImportance.High);

      this.Version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(this.AssemblyPath).FileVersion;  
    ]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

And then consume it from within a target:

```
<GetFileVersion AssemblyPath="some.dll">
  <Output TaskParameter="Version" PropertyName="MyAssemblyFileVersion" />
</GetFileVersion>
<Message Text="File version is $(MyAssemblyFileVersion)" />
```

Answer (score 4):

The [MSBuild Extension](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/) Pack has a [MaxAssemblyFileVersion](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.2.0/html/6165808c-782f-82d1-983e-963e6465def0.htm) property that may be useful.

**UPDATE:**

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164296.aspx) it doesn't look like the `GetAssemblyIdentity` task returns the `FileVersion`.

> The items output by the Assemblies parameter contain item metadata
>   entries named Version, PublicKeyToken, and Culture.

Also, see the following StackOverflow post.

[Read AssemblyFileVersion from AssemblyInfo post-compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252002/read-assemblyfileversion-from-assemblyinfo-post-compile)

Comment: This is an old question but I have the same need and wonder if this has been solved reading the DLL not the assemblyinfo.cs file ?