# GetAssemblyIdentity Version always 1.0.0.0

Tags: msbuild

The Version is 1.0.0.0 even though both the file version and product version are defined in the DLL and display correctly when I view its properties in Windows 7. Any suggestions?

```
  <Target Name="TestingAssemblyIdentity">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="MyCSharp.dll">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="assemblyInfo"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Message Text="GetAssemblyIdentity Version is %(assemblyInfo.Version)" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`GetAssemlyIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164296(v=vs.100).aspx) task returns the assembly version ([AssemblyVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx)), not the file or product version. The later are not part of the assembly's identity.

Note that assembly version and assembly file/product version serve different [purposes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556041).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1252002/21567) for a possible way to read the file version from within msbuild.

Comment: Thanks.  I will set AssemblyVersionAttribute as well as AssemblyFileVersionAttribute in MyCSharp project.

Comment: I am using the AssemblyVersion in my Project's AssemblyInfo.cs but the version is always 0.0.0.0 ! However I am not checking the AssemblyInfo of a Dll but the AssemblyInfo of the .exe file generated by my Project. Could that be the problem?